# Coldfusion server debugging no longer working

Tags: coldfusion

My coldfusion server debugging is no longer working,...  no changes to the system, just stopped. Now instead of a nice formatted output of variables and execution times I get this:

```
    ROOT CAUSE: 
coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaObjectInstantiationException: Object Instantiation Exception.
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:121)
    at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:4638)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4609)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4550)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4528)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4484)
    at cfudf2ecfm1613536669.runPage(/opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/exception/udf.cfm:12)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfclassic2ecfm186236165._factor28(/opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/debug/classic.cfm:9)
    at cfclassic2ecfm186236165.runPage(/opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/debug/classic.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.include(CfincludeFilter.java:33)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:96)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:235)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory$1.run(JavaProxyFactory.java:101)
    ... 40 more

javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaObjectInstantiationException: Object Instantiation Exception.
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:121)
    at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:4638)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4609)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4550)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4528)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4484)
    at cfudf2ecfm1613536669.runPage(/opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/exception/udf.cfm:12)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfclassic2ecfm186236165._factor28(/opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/debug/classic.cfm:9)
    at cfclassic2ecfm186236165.runPage(/opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/debug/classic.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.include(CfincludeFilter.java:33)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:96)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:235)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory$1.run(JavaProxyFactory.java:101)
    ... 40 more

    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

What version of CF is this, and is it on Windows or something else?  My best initial guess is a bad .jar file... you might need to try a reinstall.

Comment: linux/centos, CF 8.0.1

Comment: Reinstalling is not an option on a production system at this time - still experiencing the problem though. The error above is a 500 error & it seems to be because CF can't find the error templates, but if I look on the disk they are there.

Comment: There is a line in the udf.cfm file: <cfset esapiutils = createObject("java", "coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils")> indicating to me that there should be a coldfusion/security/ESAPIUtils.cfc in the wwwroot/WEB-INF/exception  folder... there is not, nor are these folders present in my last backups ~ which were over 6 months ago while applying some updates [cumulative 4 + some security updates] anyone have any thoughts on this yet?? still fighting it.